# Which is the best database application to work with offline data?

Tags: java, database, javafx, desktop-application

I have one requirement as create a desktop application edition of one data-driven web application. This web application is currently running on MySql database.

Now as per my requirement I need to create a desktop edition which will be downloaded from the web-application along with data file and it can work without Internet connection on Windows and Mac platform.

So now I cannot use MySql here as it needs connectivity with database server. So my question is which is the best option now to use as database in my desktop edition which can be used with offline data file without any server application? Also it will be plus point if migration from MySql to that database take minimal effort.

Here are some considerations to be taken in consideration:

1. It should be capable of storing blob data.
2. It should have almost same sql structure as MySql
3. It should support ORM framework like Hibernate
4. MySql data can be transfer in its compatible structure.

Please suggest me the best option for this.

Also this will be Java based solution so I am planning to use JavaFX as UI framework. Please suggest me if there is another better option for this within Java.

Comment: Any special reasons for not considering `MySql` ?

Comment: As I have mentioned I need server-less database which can work offline so I cannot consider MySql.

Comment: SQLite, HSQL, Apache Derby...

Comment: Do you need an `embedded` database ?

Answer (score 2):

You can embed the following databases (among others) quite easily in a portable application:

- H2 Database
- HSQL Database
- Derby database

It's common practice to use one of these by default, but also allow users to configure there own database. So if they wish to use their own mysql database they have that option.

Answer (score 1):

[Stack Overflow Similar question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13069195/java-desktop-application-with-embedded-database?rq=1)

These embedded databases allow you use JDBC, JPA, Hibernate so you could properly use the same database communication/transaction code as it were on the web app server endpoint, except for new requirements though... Personally, I prefer to use HSQL DB.